# Unfortunately, Slide Menu has Stopped

Tags: android, crash, emulation

***Everything with /(star) (star)/ is what I edited unless it is a comment. After fooling around with my own code a bit I took a layout from online which included a slide menu which I thought would be neat to try and see how they work.
In MyActivity I put in my own code***

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyActivity extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    /**
     * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
     */
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    /**
     * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
     */
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    /*Chronometer mChronometer;
    double startTime;
    double millis;
    private int loop = 0;*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        /*setClick();*/
    }
    /*public void setClick() {
        Button button;

        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.aChronometer);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopWatch);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopWatch);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopWatch);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);
    }

    View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (loop == 0) {
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                mChronometer.start();
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                loop++;
            } else if (loop == 1) {
                mChronometer.stop();
                millis = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
                loop++;
            } else if (loop == 2) {
                mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Your Time is: " + (millis/1000);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
                loop = 0;
            }
        }
    };*/
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        Fragment objFragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                objFragment = new menu1_Fragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                objFragment = new menu2_Fragment();
                break;
        }
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
                break;
            case 2:
                mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((MyActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

}
```

***So After all that I deleted a menu because I only needed 2 and then changed the code of the menu1_layout.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    /*<Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/aChronometer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#111111"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stopWatch"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopWatch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/stopwatch2"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />*/

</RelativeLayout>
```

***The 2 codes worked perfectly separately so I am wondering if I messed something up. Also I will include the menu1_fragment below***

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class menu1_Fragment extends Fragment {
    View rootview;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
        return rootview;
    }

}
```

***I have been fooling around for 9 hours straight so my brain might be a little fried and I am probably missing an easy fix.***

Comment: So what is the problem ?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out. No syntax errors that I am aware of and when I run it on my emulator it just gives me that message. So I am thinking it's a stupid logic error I did somewhere, but I can't find it. Anyways I am going to get some sleep and try to fix this tomorrow hopefully.

Comment: Didn't know that existed I'll get back to you XD

Comment: Like I guessed it was a stupid mistake I just fixed. Though like my adb is exteremly screwed up same with my stuff. Usually takes 2-3 tries of me ending adb and retrying run app. Anyways thanks for letting me know the name of the logs I couldn't find it.

Comment: Nevermind I didn't fix it. My full issue is on here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402450/function-in-fragment-makes-emulator-crash)